# Dynamic parameter for .Net core controller method

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core

I have class object call CustomerBase.cs with certain properties. It acts as base class for two of my other classes : Customer.cs  and Vendor.cs . i.e

```
public class Customer: CustomerBase
public class Vendor: CustomerBase
```

I have a controller method as follows:

```
 [HttpPost("CustomerData")]
 public async Task<CustomerBase> CustomerDataAsync(CustomerBase customerBaseParam)
 { }
```

When this api controller is called by another web user , the Json body parameter will contain the $Type of the rootobject. It can contain vendor or Customer or just the CustomerBase. For now even when I am passing Vendor object as parameter, it is only keeping the customerBase properties for the customerBaseParam. Same with Customer object sent as Parameter.  How can I change the type of customerBaseParam based on the Json body parameter that is coming in.?

Am using Newtonsoft.

Comment: The answer will be different if you are using Newtonsoft.Json or System.Text.Json. You need to specify

Comment: I am using Newtonsoft.Json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than let MVC parse the JSON result for you, take in a `JObject` and find the field that identifies what type of JSON object that youre dealing with. This will let you decide what type to parse it as.

Note: You can design this to be apart of the MVC middle ware so that its abstracted away.

```
[HttpPost("CustomerData")]
public async Task<CustomerBase> CustomerDataAsync(JObject customerBaseJson)
{
    var customerBaseIdentifier = customerBaseJson["fieldNameWithinTheJsonPayload"];

    //This should really be a strategy pattern to adhere to the SOLID open close principle.
    switch(customerBaseIdentifier) {
        case "type 1":
            var type1Object = JsonConvert.Deserialize<Type1>(customerBaseJson);
            break;
        case ...
    }
}
```